# I want to delete a document in cloud firestore, but I want to show a confirmation using a dialog box first that will confirm or cancel the delete

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete a document in cloud firestore, instead of deleting it directly I want to show a confirmation using a dialog box in flutter first that will confirm or cancel the deletion of document.

by clicking the delete icon, the dialog box will show so that the user can choose a command, because in my current code, it will directly delete the document in firebase.

```
        class _TabPage3State extends State<TabPage3> {
      final Stream<QuerySnapshot> driver =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('driversInfo').snapshots();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                        stream: driver,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Somethinng went wrong!');
                          }
                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text('loading...');
                          }

                          final data = snapshot.requireData;

                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.size,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: bgColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              // Instead of direct deleting the document in firebase, I want to show a dialog box first to confirm and cancel
                                              IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                      .collection("driversInfo")
                                                      .doc(
                                                          '${data.docs[index]['plate number']}')
                                                      .delete();
                                                },
                                                icon: Icon(
                                                  Icons.delete,
                                                  color: red,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        })),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update your onPressed to this:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final result = await showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
      content: const Text('This action will permanently delete this data'),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
          child: const Text('Delete'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  if (result == null || !result) {
    return;
  }

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('driversInfo')
      .doc(
        '${data.docs[index]['plate number']}',
      )
      .delete();
}
```

This will show an AlertDialog for the user to confirm, if the user pressed on "Delete", it will return true (`Navigator.pop(context, true)`). If the user pressed on the background or on "Cancel" it will return null (background) or false (Cancel).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your delete method inside the button **onPressed** which is connected with **AlertDialog**.

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

```
  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () { },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("This is my message."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```